# Is this matrix an example of a general type of matrices?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Does a matrix like the following have a name?

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & y(1)-y(0) & y(2)-y(1) & y(3)-y(2) & y(4)-y(3) & y(5)-y(4) \\
 y(0)-y(5) & 0 & y(2)-y(0) & y(3)-y(1) & y(4)-y(2) & y(5)-y(3) \\
 y(0)-y(4) & y(1)-y(5) & 0 & y(3)-y(0) & y(4)-y(1) & y(5)-y(2) \\
 y(0)-y(3) & y(1)-y(4) & y(2)-y(5) & 0 & y(4)-y(0) & y(5)-y(1) \\
 y(0)-y(2) & y(1)-y(3) & y(2)-y(4) & y(3)-y(5) & 0 & y(5)-y(0) \\
 y(0)-y(1) & y(1)-y(2) & y(2)-y(3) & y(3)-y(4) & y(4)-y(5) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

To get the entries below the diagonal, simply take the corresponding diagonal above the principal diagonal, multiply it by -1 and reverse it.

Eg. taking the the 1st diagonal above the principal diagonal, produces

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 y(1)-y(0) & y(2)-y(0) & y(3)-y(0) & y(4)-y(0) & y(5)-y(0) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

(I represent it as a row-vector to ease presentation).

Multiplying it by -1 and reversing, yields

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 y(0)-y(5) & y(0)-y(4) & y(0)-y(3) & y(0)-y(2) & y(0)-y(1) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

which is a row representation of the column vector below the diagonal, shown above.

Comment: A distance matrix?

Comment: @user619894 the difference is not an important feature, it could have been division instead or some other function (with an inverse) of two arguments ; I'm interested in the structure of the elements, their relative positions, if that makes sense

Comment: Basically the form is $[Y^T,\cdots,Y^T]-\begin{bmatrix}{Y\\ \vdots\\Y}\end{bmatrix}$. If you replace the $-$ with a division, you will get the ratio format

Comment: @user619894 I don't think the form works; consider how the eg. 3rd column of the result would look like: $(y(0),y(1),y(2),y(3),y(4),y(5))-(y(2),y(2),y(2),y(2),y(2),y(2))$ and contrast it with the matrix in the the question; unless I missed something, they don't match

Comment: right, I missed that...